# Problema con un tipo "enum"

Tags: java

Quiero modelar una clase del tipo Enum como esta:

```
public enum TNivel
{
   99/200, 2000/2001, 2001/2002
}
```

Pero me da error. Si encierro los valores entre comillas dobles "99/200", "2000/2001", "2001/2002" también me da error

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: Los identificadores del enum deben seguir la misma regla usada para nombres de variables por lo tanto `200/100` es inválido, `"200/100"` también.

Comment: Como comenta, Lobos, ese nombren o es válido par ael enum. En Java hay dos tipos de enums, los simples y los compuestos. Los primeros, se componene de una sola palabra, que debe estar, creo recordar, en mayúsculas (por convención). Y los segundos, los compuestos, son iguales a los primeros, pero, además, pueden tener valores asociados. Dichos valores van entre paréntesis. Sería conveniente que buscaras algo de información sobre los enums en Java. Tu problema es muy sencillo de resolver. Solo debes darle un nombre válido a los valores del enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```java
public enum TNivel {
  NOMBRE_QUE_TU_QUIERAS1("99/200"), NOMBRE_QUE_TU_QUIERAS2("2000/2001"), NOMBRE_QUE_TU_QUIERAS3("2001/2002")

  private String nivel;
  public TNivel(String nivel){
    this.nivel = nivel;
  }

  public getNivel(){
    return nivel;
  }
}
```

Para usar el enum y obtener el String ingresado puedes hacer:

```java
String tNivel = TNivel.NOMBRE_QUE_TU_QUIERAS1.getNivel();

// tNivel -> "99/200"
```

Te recomiendo que leas la documentación oficial sobre [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Se considera de baja calidad responder solo con codigo, porfavor leer.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @AntoniSamillanDeLaCruz gracias por el comentario, añadí el link a la documentación oficial. saludos